# Bluetooth and Sound not Working

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, audio, bluetooth

My Bluetooth and sound are not working in Ubuntu. I reinstalled Windows 11 and there is also a problem with drivers. I contacted the service center and they provided me custom drivers and my Bluetooth and sound got fixed, but when I asked for Linux they didn't have any suggestions.

I tried different distros, but none of them detected my Bluetooth and there wasn't any sound from the speakers. Although there is an increase or decrease volume slider, I can't hear any sound. Also the Bluetooth option is disabled and it's not working. Does anyone know how can I get drivers for my Ubuntu?

My system specs are here.

- System: Ubuntu 23.10
- Arch: x86_64
- Kernel: 6.5.0-14-generic
- Vendor: Infinix
- Model: INBOOK X3 Slim
- Year: 2023
- HWid: AE207 »
- Type: laptop
- DE: Ubuntu:GNOME (Wayland) - GDM3
- inxi results [Here](https://pastebin.com/JFeT3hc4)

Updated Results:

- HW probe results [Here](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=a62bc72974)
- My Windows installed Driver list in which everything is working fine, in case needed [Here](https://pastebin.com/XmmHZ4Bk)

Answer (score 1):

The HW probe results included your `dmesg` output, which indicates you are missing the firmware file for your Bluetooth feature:

```
[    4.262744] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load Intel firmware file intel/ibt-0040-1050.sfi (-2)
```

In Ubuntu 23.10, the firmware file is in package `linux-firmware`. Make sure that package is installed and up to date. Once the package is installed, the firmware file should be at `/lib/firmware/intel/ibt-0040-1050.sfi`.

For the sound, I'm not so sure but I think you might need the `firmware-sof-signed` package too. It's another package of firmware files required by the newer Intel chipset-integrated sound features.

Comment: Bluetooth is fixed from above solution but sound doesn't. i reinstall linux firmware from https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git now it says firmware-sof-signed is already newest version 2.2.6-1ubuntu1.2 but sound doesn't comes from speaker. I also update hwprobe result as new firmware installed. Please check and suggest.

Comment: According to your hwprobe, the mixer chip in your sound solution is a Realtek ALC269VB... and a bit of Googling indicates some other systems with that chip have apparently had the speaker and the headphone outputs crosswired/mislabeled(?) in the firmware, which is reflected in the audio settings. Try running `alsamixer -c 0` and unmuting and increasing the volume of the headphone output; if it actually affects the speakers, the mislabeling can be persistently corrected using the `hdajackretask` tool (in the `alsa-tools-gui` package).

Comment: See almixer output https://imgur.com/a/26e5uzJ

Comment: Your headphone channel is muted (`MM` at the bottom instead of `OO`). Use arrow keys to move to that column, then press the M key to toggle the mute state. Note that there are still some more columns outside the window to the right: use cursor keys to try and move "off the screen" to the right to get them into view, or just make the window wider.

Comment: Yes see here https://imgur.com/Sv3gphd

Comment: Okay, unmute also the first "S/PDIF" channel (just to be sure), and try playing some sounds while moving the Master and Headphone volume sliders up to the max using the arrow keys. If there is still no sound, then it's not the ALC269VB mislabeling issue, but something different.

Comment: When i reboot system headphones automatically get muted. How to save after change it

Comment: Unmuted everything still no sound - https://imgur.com/a/fdBix4X  my sound section detect playing sound https://imgur.com/a/22UajeU but i cant hear it from speaker